# PHP assign same value to multiple variables in this case

Tags: php

I need to assign the same value to different variables, but cannot do it like this because some of the are like this `$var_a .= blah'`

`$var_a = $var_b = $same_var = $var_d = $some_var = 'A';`

Is there another way to assign the same value to multiple variables?

Something like `$var_a .=, $var_b .= 'this value'`

Comment: AFAIK, nope there's no such way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a single line? No, as far as I know, but this would be a horrible style in my opinion.

Use this:

```
$var_a .= 'this value';
$var_b .= 'this value';
```

If you really want a one-liner, try this:

```
list($a, $b) = array_map(function($i) {return $i . 'EXT';}, array($a, $b));
```